# Webscraping with Python3.7: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443):

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to scrape web results from google.com. I followed the first answer from this questions, [Google Search Web Scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619478/google-search-web-scraping-with-python). Unfortunately I am getting connecting error. I happened to check with other websites too, its not connecting . Is it because of the corporate proxy settings?

Please note that i am using virtual env "Webscraping".

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs

from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get

raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow").text
page = fromstring(raw)

for result in page.cssselect(".r a"):
    url = result.get("href")
    if url.startswith("/url?"):
        url = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q']
    print(url[0])
```

> raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow").text
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow").text
>
> File
> "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\webscraping\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 75, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\webscraping\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 60, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\webscraping\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 524, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File
> "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\webscraping\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 637, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\webscraping\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 516, in send
> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>
> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443):
> Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=StackOverflow (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
> at 0x0000021B79768748>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Please advise. Thanks

EDIT: I tried pining google.com, it fails.

```
import os
hostname = "https://www.google.com" #example
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

#and then check the response...
if response == 0:
  print(hostname, 'is up!')
else:
  print(hostname, 'is down!')
```

> https://www.google.com is down!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting this error because of your proxy setting.
Try run one of the following commands in command prompt

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy_address:port
set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy_address:port
set https_proxy=https://proxy_address:port
set https_proxy=https://user:password@proxy_address:port
```