# Error while parsing google search result using urllib in python

Tags: python

So i started learning web scraping in python using urllib and bs4,

I was searching for a code to analyze and i found this:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38620894/14252018
here is the code:-

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs

from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get

raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow").text
page = fromstring(raw)

for result in page.cssselect(".r a"):
    url = result.get("href")
    if url.startswith("/url?"):
        url = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['q']
    print(url[0])
```

When i try to run this it does not print anything

[image: I named it as webparse.py]

So then i tried using bs4 and this time i chose https://www.duckduckgo.com

and changed the code to this:-

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dinosaur&t=h_&ia=web').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

print(soup.get_text())
```

I got an error:-

[image]

1. Why didn't the first block of code run?
2. why did the second block of code gave me an error? and what does that error mean?

Comment: Perhaps try `cssselect(".r.a")` if you're searching for elements with class="r a" or class="a r"

Comment: and why did the second bloack of code gave an error, and what does that mean?

Comment: Why do you assume that the duckduckgo message was an error? The message just shows that duckduckgo detected that javascript is not understood and that duckduckgo is redirecting you to a different page.

Comment: But it did not print anything other than that

Comment: What else did you expect the 2nd block of code to print out?

Comment: The whole html code other than the tags

Comment: "The whole html code other than the tags" but that only appears if you follow the redirect which you did not do. `urllib.request.urlopen` does not follow redirects automatically. By default, `requests.get` will follow redirects.

Comment: Yeah done but how can i find the <b> tags?

Comment: The second block of code works in some websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your duckduckgo URL to where the site tries to redirect you when javascript is not enabled.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

# url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dinosaur&t=h_&ia=web' # uses javascript
url = 'https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=dinosaur' # no javascript

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Because nothing matched your CSS selector. Google shows different pages depending on whether javascript is enabled or not. Neither urllib nor requests do javascript.