# How to Scrape Google's quick answer box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, pycharm

I want to scrape quick answer box of google(e.g., the selected text):

[image: 1]

I've checked other questions asked on the website regarding the same but that didn't help. How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Search Web Scraping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619478/google-search-web-scraping-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you ,
have given gold rate in search

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=gold+rate+india&safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN960IN960&ei=9qksYc76FeeS4-EP-8iQ8AY&oq=gold+rate+india&gs_lcp=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&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjOza2jvNjyAhVnyTgGHXskBG4Q4dUDCA8&uact=5', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

result = soup.find('div', class_='vlzY6d')
print(result.text)
```

Comment: It's returning **None**. And showing _Import "lxml" could not be resolved_ as a problem...

Comment: works fine for me have added import can u try it with this ? if ur trying on vscode  add this in vscode setting json "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./path-to-code/"],

Comment: tried this still it's returning "None" :(

Comment: ohk can u try after pip install lxml

Comment: Thank you so much... Uninstalled and installed lxml again and it's working now :)

Comment: wanted to ask one more question. I am facing issue while scraping this HTML below :

Comment: <div style="margin-left:-20px" class="LTKOO sY7ric"><div style="display:inline" data-dobid="dfn"><span>the abstract science of number, quantity, and space, either as abstract concepts ( <i>pure mathematics</i> ), or as applied to other disciplines such as physics and engineering ( <i>applied mathematics</i> ).</span></div><div class="vmod"><div class="ubHt5c">"a taste for mathematics"</div></div></div>

Comment: I tried writing like this `result = soup.find('div', class_= 'LTKOO sY7ric')
          print(result.span.text)
          speak(result.span.text)`

Comment: Facing this issue: `You: what is the meaning of mathematics           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\MY Programmes\DUSTIN- THE VOICE ASSISTANT\dustin.py", line 106, in <module>
    print(result.span.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'`

Comment: can u ping exactly where uyou are trying to scrape

Comment: just try with result.text